# Creating LDA model using gensim from bag-of-words vectors

Tags: vector, lda, topic-modeling, jstor

I want to create a topic model from data provided by Jstor (e.g. https://www.jstor.org/dfr/about/sample-datasets). However, because of copyright, they do not allow full text access. Instead, I can request a list of unigrams followed by their frequencies in the document (supplied in plain `.txt`). e.g:

```
his         295
old         181
he          165
age         152
p           110
from         79
life         74
de           71
petrarch     58
book         51
courtier     47
```

This should be easy to convert to a bag-of-words vector. However, I have only found examples of Gensim LDA models being built from fulltext. Would it be possible to pass it these vectors instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you only need to convert `(word, frequency)` to `(word_number, frequency)`, and pass a list of tuples to `corpus` of any gensim model. To convert a word to a number, you can first count how many words are in the whole corpus, suppose we have *V* words, then each word can be represented as an integer between 1 to *V*.